# Correct way to trim a file name to use as a string?

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a javaFX project using data from files in a  data directory as input. I want to use each file name as a String variable. I have already loaded the data:

```
File path = new File("data");
File [] files = path.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    if (files[i].isFile()){ 
       items.loadData(files[i].toString());
    }
```

The toString is now data/fileName1.csv. I want to save use fileName1 only. I have tried using the split() method in the loadData() method, like this:

```
fileName= fileName.split("/")[1]; //should trim to fileName1.csv, works
fileName= fileName.split("\.")[0]; //should trim to fileName1, error
```

The error for the second split() is "invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )".

I have tried variations to fix this. Is there a better/more efficient way to accomplish this?

Edit: Changed trim to split

Comment: `I have tried using the trim() method in the loadData() method` I don't see where you used `trim()`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape your backslash. Try `\\.`

But for operations like this, you should probably use Path functions such as: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName()

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code and get the filename in just one line.

```
files[i].substring(files[i].indexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: What if it's Windows and they use ' \' ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :

```
String fileName = "data/fileName1.csv";
String [] arr = fileName.split("(/|\\.)");
fileName = arr[1];
```